# How make a date range array in Ruby that starts with the current month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

Thanks to [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477037/stefan) I was able to create a function that returns a number of date ranges:

```
def years
  [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]
end

def month_ranges
  years.flat_map { |y|
    12.downto(1).map { |m| Date.new(y,m,1)..Date.new(y,m,-1) }
  }
end

# => 

[
  Mon, 01 Dec 2013..Wed, 31 Dec 2013, 
  Sat, 01 Nov 2013..Sun, 30 Nov 2013, 
  Wed, 01 Oct 2013..Fri, 31 Oct 2013, 
  Mon, 01 Sep 2013..Tue, 30 Sep 2013
]
```

Now, is there a way to make this date array start with the **current** month of the current year as well? In the following years it should always start with December and end with January.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: The output you show is Rails' doing, right (don't know Rails)?

Comment: I think it's the output from Ruby's [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class?

Comment: In Ruby 2.0.0 (and I expect in earlier versions), from docs, `Date.new(2001,2,3)        #=> #<Date: 2001-02-03 ...>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: check the year against the current year. If they're equal, start with current month, if not start with 12.

```
years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]

def month_ranges
  years.flat_map { |y|
    if y == Date.today.year
      start = Date.today.month
    else
      start = 12
    end
    start.downto(1).map { |m| Date.new(y,m,1)..Date.new(y,m,-1) }
  }
end
```

Comment: `@years` or `def years.. end`

Answer (score 2):

To provide the result in the format required in the earlier question:

```
require 'date'
years = [2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009]
years.map(&:to_s).product([*'-01'..'-12'].reverse).map(&:join).select{|d| d <= Date.today.to_s[0..-3]}
```

=> ["2013-09", "2013-08",..., "2009-01"]